# Why Trained and Loaded Model is giving different evaluate result? 82% vs 5%

Tags: tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, computer-vision, training-data

I implemented my seq-Keras model and it was successfully trained.

```
...
model.fit(...)
...
>>Result:  Successfully completed: TrainAcc=99%, ValAcc=88%
```

**Next:**
NOW I run this code:

```
model.save('Model88.h5')
model.evaluate(X_test, y_test)
   Result >> accuracy: 0.8216
```

**Next:**
but when I load the saved model(Model88) and evaluate that:

```
model = keras.models.load_model('Model88.h5')
model.evaluate(X_test, y_test)
    Result >>  accuracy: 0.0214 !!!
```

The test data is the same, the saved model and the loaded model are the same!

Why does this happen? accuracy: **82% -> 5%** !!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had same problem before and i found out that test accuracy was calculated wrongly during training. I had changed test batch size to 1 to fix it.

Comment: Thanks for the prompt response :) Yes, you are right!! I find the answer! solution for value of evaluation is 1-I was wrong, I should not use:  `X-test`, `x-test` is right!!!   but, train and load data still different!!  solution: 2- I should only use `Keras` or use **JUST** `Tensorflow.Keras`, My mistake was to use the `Tensorflow.Keras` and `Keras` packages at the **same time.**